# How to disable the on hover display of expand arrow in GUI treeviewer? I want them to always be visible

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, treeviewer

How can I disable the on hover display of expand arrow in my GUI's treeviewer? I want the expand arrows to always be visible, I'm not sure but I think this is a feature of Windows GUI. Is there a workaround for this to have the arrows always visible so the user knows the fields are expandable (clickable) and not just lines displayed. The expand arrows are only visible on hover of the mouse. See attached image the first image is the default view. The one below is what I get on hover of the mouse.

[image: See on the image attached to this link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed in Eclipse 3.8. The expand arrows do not disappear anymore after upgrading my target platform from Eclipse 3.7 to Eclipse 3.8 which means that the arrows are visible without hovering on top of them. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by the native control that SWT uses to draw the tree. SWT does not have an option to change this.

The details of how the tree view look vary significantly on the different platforms supported by SWT. For example on Macs the expand 'twistie' is always shown.